# Ngrx effects in angular application

Tags: javascript, angular-2+

```
@Effect()
createQuiz$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<quizAction.CreateQuiz>(quizAction.CREATE_QUIZ),
    switchMap((action) => {
        return this.quizService.createQuiz(action.payload)
        .pipe(
        map(() => {
            return new quizAction.CreateQuizCompleted()
        }),
        catchError(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return of(new quizAction.CreateQuizCompleted());
        })
        );

    })
);
    

export class QuizComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private quizService: QuizService, 
    private store:Store<{app: fromApp.State}>,
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  trackByIdx = (index: number): number => index;

  onCreate(): void {
    this.store.select(fromApp.selectUserId).pipe(
      take(1)
    ).subscribe(userId => this.handleCreate(userId));
  }

  handleCreate(userId: string): void {
    let value = this.quizService.createDefaultQuiz();
    if (this.quizService.hasPermission(userId) && this.quizService.validateQuiz(value)) {
      this.store.dispatch(new quizAction.CreateQuiz(value));
    }
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there's any memory leak that can occur or any non-idiomatic patterns that I am using without knowing. Does everything look fine?